# Google charts not working with jquery load function

Tags: c#, jquery, google-visualization

I am using Google charts api to draw a table chart.
I am making an `ajax` call using jquery in this way -

```
$('#table_div').load('getAnalysis.aspx');
```

Here I am populating `<div id=table_div"></div>` using `load` function of `jquery`.
Now `getAnalysis.aspx` returns following html text -

```
<div id="iqr_table"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(iqr_drawTable);
    function iqr_drawTable() {
      var iqr_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'Q #');          
      iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'My Answer');
      iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'Correct Answer');
      iqr_data.addRows([
    ['1', 'A', 'C', ],
    ['2', '', 'C,D', ],
    ['3', 'C', 'C', ],
    ['4', 'D', 'D', ],
    ['5', 'C,D', 'A,B', ],
   ]);

      var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('iqr_table'));
      table.draw(iqr_data, { showRowNumber: true });
}
</script>
```

I have checked using google chrome built in developer tool that ajax call is made properly and html text is correctly received, also `<script>` tag in received content is evaluated.

But immediately after evaluation of `<script>` tag something goes wrong, and `<body>` is removed from page and nothing is displayed.
I don't understand where is the mistake.

P.S : I have included all required script files in main page, so please don't point that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - Google API said to initialize the load first off. So maybe keep the google.load function out of the AJAX fetched script,

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['annotatedtimeline']}); 

$(document).ready(function(){               
// Get TIER1Tickets                 
$('#table_div').load('getAnalysis.aspx');
```

and what i get from `getAnalysis.aspx` is this (asuming that google is already initialized and package is loaded) -

```
<div id="iqr_table"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>    
  var iqr_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'Q #');          
  iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'My Answer');
  iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'Correct Answer');
  iqr_data.addRows([
  ['1', 'A', 'C', ],
  ['2', '', 'C,D', ],
  ['3', 'C', 'C', ],
  ['4', 'D', 'D', ],
  ['5', 'C,D', 'A,B', ],   

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('iqr_table'));
  table.draw(iqr_data, { showRowNumber: true });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All right, the problem is in the script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['table']
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(iqr_drawTable);

    var iqr_data = { }; // define it here.

    function iqr_drawTable() {
        /*var*/ iqr_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); // iqr_data is defined here.
        iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'Q #');
        iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'My Answer');
        iqr_data.addColumn('string', 'Correct Answer');
        iqr_data.addRows([
            ['1', 'A', 'C', ],
            ['2', '', 'C,D', ],
            ['3', 'C', 'C', ],
            ['4', 'D', 'D', ],
            ['5', 'C,D', 'A,B', ], ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('iqr_table'));
        table.draw(iqr_data, {    // and isn't available here.
            showRowNumber: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

Although I don't know why does the `<body>` need to get removed from the page...but this was the problem i could notice...

Comment: i have tried `iqr_data` fix but not working although i dont think it is required as it has limited scope. And you wrote `"and isnt available here"` so what is not available there.

Comment: all right....just because of bad indenting, i thought table.draw was called outside the function...sorry for that...